What is the next number according to some law?
Question is as follows:
8619 - 4.
1253 - 0
9273 - 1
6656 - 3
1086 - ?
What is the question mark? I tried summing the digits, checking number of 2's in prime factorization, but 2nd relation (1253 - 0) causes most problems.
Any help would be appreciated!

Welcome to Puzzling. Can you tell us where this puzzle comes from? We require proper attribution for puzzles from another source.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!  I’ve seen this type of puzzle before so I won’t answer it.

This is a cliche puzzle trick must be a duplicate question

It's a puzzle given to me by my friend. He is fan of this type of questions, I think he found it somewhere online, not really sure.

If its a duplicate can you please send a link? So i can delete this question

I put the answer below anyway. I am not sure where it is…
